# Android Studio Eel xml preview not showing, custom component missing classes

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, android-studio-electric-eel

I have recently updated Android Studio to Android Studio Electric Eel | 2022.1.1.

For xml layout if we are using simple view like TextView/Button , it is displayed on preview.
But if we are using CustomView, then it is not showing in preview.(Preview is blank)

Also it is showing error: Missing classes
[image]

My Simple Test App , main activity xml file is as

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">


    <com.example.webviewdeeplink.CustomTextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="This is Test Text"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        app:font="RobotoCondensed-LightItalic.ttf"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/button"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Custom Component class -

```
class CustomTextView : androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView {

    constructor(context: Context?, attrs: AttributeSet?, defStyle: Int) : super(
        context!!,
        attrs,
        defStyle
    ) {
        init(attrs)
    }

    constructor(context: Context?, attrs: AttributeSet?) : super(context!!, attrs) {

        init(attrs)
    }

    constructor(context: Context?) : super(context!!) {

        init(null)
    }


    private fun init(attrs: AttributeSet?) {
        if (attrs != null) {
            val a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.CustomTextView)
            val fontName = a.getString(R.styleable.CustomTextView_font)
            try {
                if (fontName != null) {
                    val myTypeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(
                        context.assets,
                        "fonts/$fontName"
                    )
                    setTypeface(myTypeface)
                }
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                e.printStackTrace()
            }
            a.recycle()
        }
    }
}
```

If any one faced this issue , could you please confirm issue.
OR this is known Android Studio Issue?

Comment: Try rebuilding the project and open the layout again.

Answer (score 1):

1. Change the build variant to debug
2. Clean and Rebuild the project

This will fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

try this code...

```
constructor(context: Context?, attrs: AttributeSet?, defStyle: Int) : super(
    context!!,
    attrs,
    0
) {
    init(attrs)
}
```

Replace `defStyle` with `0`